# Python subprocess don't output to file when called in a loop

Tags: python, loops, subprocess

Can anyone explain to me why when I open a sub-process and tells it to output to file it works :

```
currentSharePath = '\\\Path1'
p = subprocess.Popen([r'powershell.exe',
              '-ExecutionPolicy',
              'Bypass',
              os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'\subFoldersClassifier.ps1',
              '-sharePath',
              currentSharePath,
              '2>$null',
              '| Out-File -encoding utf8 -append classified_subFolders.txt'], 
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

But when I call it in a loop the output is shown on my terminal instead of the file:

```
    with open('found_shares_cleaned.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()


for currentSharePath in content:
    p = subprocess.Popen([r'powershell.exe',
                  '-ExecutionPolicy',
                  'Bypass',
                  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))+'\subFoldersClassifier.ps1',
                  '-sharePath',
                  currentSharePath,
                  '2>$null',
                  '| Out-File -encoding utf8 -append classified_subFolders.txt'], 
                  stdout=sys.stdout)
    p.communicate()
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the loop, it's the `readlines()` method which inserts a newline character in the end of each line.

so one of your argument contains a newline, which may be enough to end the command line (and skip the redirection, done in the next line, which does nothing)

Possible fix, `strip` the trailing newline:

```
for currentSharePath in content:
    currentSharePath = currentSharePath.rstrip()
```

or generate your list of lines like this:

```
with open('found_shares_cleaned.txt') as f:
    content = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```